# Kubernetes Java Pods Socket communication

Tags: java, kubernetes

I have been playing with Kubernetes and Docker, and I was trying to recreate a setup that I use. My old setup is multiple java game servers running, and I have them connected using netty and a main server. I wanted to change these to kubernetes' pods. Do I still need to use a main server for netty's socket communication? Or does kubernetes offer a native TCP Socket communication?

Comment: Can you expand what are you trying to do? I don't follow on what you mean by native TCP Socket communication, Kubernetes does helps you if what you are trying to do is discover other server in the system.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I'm guessing you're running a clustered application and one of the instances in the cluster is the designated leader/master. If it's designated in a static way then you might be able to use one Deployment for the leader and another for the workers so that you can scale separately. If it's dynamically-elected that's different (https://kubernetes.io/blog/2016/01/simple-leader-election-with-kubernetes/)

You can also run multiple containers in a single Pod. Or multiple apps in a Container. Then you don't get the benefits of the platform's facilities to scale up replicas in response to load. It depends on your reasons for porting. A link that may be of interest is https://github.com/PaulSandoz/jersey-netty-app/blob/master/Tutorial.md